# How can I get the first letter of first and last row name in every page?

Tags: php, sql

I wrote a PHP code to display data from database order by name ASC and then data was divided into pages with each holding up to 20 records each.

I wish to add more into it, e.g. after each page number some information will show displaying first letter of first name (1st record) - first letter of last name (last record).

Like:

```
1(A-H), 2(H-P), 3(P-U), 4(U-Z)
```

Here, first page contains records and inside it first record (first letter of name) and last record(first letter of last name)

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tssolutions";

$results_per_page = 20;

//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

//echo "connected successfully";

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $results_per_page;

//actual query to show
$sql = "select name, phone, details, photo from phone order by name asc LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_page;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

        echo "<div class='w3-row-padding w3-grayscale'>";
        echo "<style>
img.chip 
 {
    float:left;
    height:25%;
    width:25%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

</style>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    //output data of each row 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<div class='w3-col 3 m3 w3-margin-bottom w3-border w3-btn w3-padding w3-white' style='text-color:black;min-width:300px;'>";
        echo "<div class='w3-half'>";
        if(base64_encode( $row['photo'] )== !NULL )
        {
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['photo'] ).'" class="chip" style="height:120px;width:120px;margin-top:20px;">';        
        }
        else
        {
        echo "<img src='./images/noimage.jpg' alt='Jane' class='chip' style='height:120px;width:120px;margin-top:20px;'>";
        }
        echo "</div><div class='w3-half'>";
        echo "</h3>" .$row['name']. "</h3>";
        echo "<p class='w3-opacity'>" .$row['phone']. "</p>";
        echo "<p style='text-align:justify'>" .$row['details']. "</p>";
        echo "<p><button class='w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block'>Contact</button></p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

    }
            echo "</div>";
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$anothersql = "SELECT COUNT(name) AS total FROM phone"; 
$anotherresult = $conn->query($anothersql);
$anotherrow = $anotherresult->fetch_assoc();

$total_pages = ceil($anotherrow["total"] / $results_per_page); // calculate total pages with results
  echo"
  <style>
  a
  {
      text-decoration:none;
  }
  .curPage
  {
    text-decoration:underline;  
    font-size:30px;
  }

  </style>
  ";


              echo"<div style='text-align:center;margin-bottom:3px;';><h4>";

  for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  // print links for all pages

            echo "<a href='alumni.php?page=".$i."'";
            if ($i==$page)  echo "class='curPage'";
            echo ">".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
};
   echo "</h4></div>";

mysqli_close($conn);

echo "<hr>";
?>
```

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you want to add the starting letters of first name of each page to your pagination.

The only way i can think of  is to add a query in pagination loop which selects only the first entry of the page and then format the result to show only the first letters, but that would be bad performance wise.

What i would do is create filters to show all entries that start with each letter ( ALL A B C D... )

```
echo "<a href='alumni.php'>ALL </a>";
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
    echo "<a href='alumni.php?name=" . $char . "'>" . $char . " </a>";
}
```

And change the part which is commented "Actual query to show" to something like

```
if( isset( $_GET['name'] ) ) {      
    $letter = substr( $_GET['name'], 0, 1 );    
    $sql = "select name, phone, details, photo from phone WHERE name LIKE '".$letter."%' order by name asc LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_page;
} else 
    $sql = "select name, phone, details, photo from phone order by name asc LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_page;
}
```

Comment: Does it sort records in groups , where result is starting with the letter i choose ?
I tried it (your answer ) but somehow its not working , no change is observed when i click any of them below .

Comment: Sorry i wrote the first code badly, copy+paste it again.

Comment: Thank You, that was useful 
You Saved the day : ) .

Comment: Glad to help :)